# Google Geocoder loading issue

Tags: google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

After reviewing Google API documentation I remain confused. I want to use the Google Geocoding API but the console throws the error

> Geocoder is not defined

What is causing it to throw this error after having  defined it with

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Here is my code for the maps

```
GoogleMaps.ready('locationRadiusMap', function(map) {

        var markers = [];
        var input = $("#pac-input")[0];
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        var instance = GoogleMaps.maps.locationRadiusMap.instance;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        // instance.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function(m) {

              function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, information) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                   var userlat = Session.get('userlat');
                   var userlng = Session.get('userlng');
                   var latLng = userlat.toString() + ", " + userlng.toString();

                    var latLngStr = latLng.split(",", 2);
                    var latLngLocate = {
                        lat: parseFloat(latLngStr[0]),
                        lng: parseFloat(latLngStr[1])
                    };
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'location': latLngLocate
                    }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status === Geocoder.status.OK) {
                            if (results[1]) {
                                console.log(results[1].formatted_address);
                            }
                        } 
                        else {
                            window.alert('No results found');
                        } 

                    });
                }

            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
                // areaCircle.setMap(null);
            });

            markers = [];

            places.forEach(function(place) {
                var image = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };


                var areaCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    map: map.instance,
                    center: place.geometry.location,
                    zoom: 7,
                    radius: 8093.4,
                    strokeColor: "#f8504b",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#f8504b",
                    fillOpacity: 0.4
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map.instance,
                    icon: image,
                    title: place.name,
                    draggable: true,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });

                // Create a marker for each place.

                markers.push(marker);
                console.log(marker);


                var userlat = marker.getPosition().lat();
                var userlng = marker.getPosition().lng();

                var locate = marker.getPosition();
                console.log(locate);


                Session.set("userlat", userlat);
                Session.set("userlng", userlng);

                console.log(userlat, userlng);
                var latLng = userlat.toString() + ", " + userlng.toString();

                geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map);

                var mape = map.instance;
                mape.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

this loads in the map with app key

```
GoogleMaps.load({
        v: '3',
        key: 'KEYHERE',
        libraries: 'geometry,places'
    });
```

Comment: Should I always use the JS code box even if it's just a single line Adam? just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blowing up on this line:

```
if (status === Geocoder.status.OK) {
```

Try this:

```
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
```

google.maps.GeocoderStatus should exist, but Geocoder doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried both options you gave and it gave another error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OK' of undefined .

Comment: Try adding this line just after defining geocoder: console.log(google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK). The version I'm testing google with is able to find this ok, and it's in the official docs so if it's not working in your callback then I'm stumped...

Comment: It works now, thanks, I added the console.log and now it magically works when it logs out that value.